# How to pass parameters to controllers in codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in mysql which has 2 tables one named category(cat_id primary key) and one named book(b_id as primary key) where cat_id is a foreign key for book.
I'm working in CI and here I output the categories in a view:

```html
        foreach($categories->result()as $row){
             foreach($categories->result()as $row){
        echo '<a href="category_details?cat_id=$cat_id">'.$row->category.'</a><br>';

    }

        }
```

I want that when clicking to the link `category_details` to output just the books of that category.
Here I have this method in my controller:

```html
public function category_details($data)
    {
        $data['cat_id'] = $this->home_model->output_cat_detail();
        $data['category_detail'] = $this->home_model->output_cat_detail();//printon librat
        $data['categories'] = $this->home_model->output_categories();
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('category_details', $data);


    }
```

So the method in model which does that selection is this:

```html
public function output_cat_detail(){
    $condition = "cat_id =" . "'" . $data['cat_id'] . "'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('book');
   $this->db->where($condition);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

But after I do this when I click in a category all the books appear not just the books of that category I have clicked. Can someone help me with the condition to select just the books of that category?

Comment: here `<a href="category_details">` you have to append category_id too like:- `<a href="category_details?id = $cat_id">` and then change `category_details($id)` and then a where query something like:-`SELECT * FROM books WHERE cat_id= $id`;

Comment: I didnt unerstand only this :change category_details($id). What do u mean by that?

Comment: change function name like this. Pass id as parameter there

Comment: Yes but maybe the parameter shoud be passed to the  output_cat_detail?

Comment: Yes its codeigniter

Comment: Nope. It outputs some errors. I dont know if I can pass params to the controler.

Comment: Yes I changed it. Im editing the question with the changes.

Comment: check this link that how can you pass id to controller through link in view:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/15061114/4248328

Answer (score 0):

```
public function category_details($id){
    $data = array();
    $data['category_detail'] = "";
    $query = $this->db->get_where('book', array('id' => $id));
    // Your current model logic will not work for this
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $data['category_detail'] = $query->result();
    }
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('category_details', $data);
}
```

Comment: OIt says undefined variable id

Comment: Where should it take this variable $id?